# How can I sync purchased audible audiobooks from iPhone Books app to MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, books, monterey

I purchased an audiobook, that is presented by audible, in my iPhone's Books app. Now, I want to have the same book in my MacBook Pro's Books app and listen to it and read its attached PDFs. I expected it to automatically appear there without any extra configuration or anything. But, it didn't. I checked "Download new purchases automatically" and it didn't have any effect.

[image]

I also ensured that Books.app is checked in iCloud Drive options in System preferences -> Aple ID.

[image]

What else should I do?

I have macOS Monterey 12.2.1 and Books 4.2.

Comment: 1 Disable low power mode on ios.  2 iphone also has some settings about syncing ibooks. Check there also.

Comment: Thanks, @anki for the comment. The low power mode is off. I set all the settings about syncing iBooks that I found. None of them worked.